# export a savedmodel pb from tensorflow's example retrain.py

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have come across this repository:
https://github.com/ArunMichaelDsouza/tensorflow-image-detection that utilizes tensorflow's example code:
https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py

I had tried modifying `retrain.py` to get it to export a `SavedModel` `(saved_model.pb and a folder named variables)` to convert to a client-side javascript model. `(tfjs_graph_model)`
From hours of researching, I first found out I can't convert a frozen model, and the only way I could export a `SavedModel` was using tensorflow's built in `SavedModelBuilder`, but I have no idea how to incorporate that into the code.
I looked at examples like
https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/example/mnist_saved_model.py
but I don't even know where the `x` and `y` variables are in the `retrain.py` file.

My goal is to get it to export a `SavedModel` so I can use `tensorflowjs_converter`to convert that into `tfjs_graph_model`

Edit: I'm a noobie to python and tensorflow (not to javascript tho) so please answer with a code snippet for the `retrain.py` file to export the `SavedModel` using the `SavedModelBuilder` along with comments for each step. Thanks! ^.^